# I can not find informations about Hisilicon kirin 650

Tags: performance

I want to know if Hisilcon Kirin 650 is a heterogenous or a homogenous processor!!
(working all 8 cores or  4 by 4, not in the same time )
Please answer to my question !!

Comment: Did you seriously even try to Google this? I found the answer in seconds by doing nothing but googling `Kirin 650 specs`

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.shafa.com/articles/zg2RKxNxXwvtjvj8.html) is a Chinese review of Huawei G9 Lite, which has K650 built-in. As can be seen from the AIDA64 screenshot below, all cores are of the same arch, and are online at the same time, albeit at different freqs.

[image]

Comment: Actually the K650 is heterogenous, 4 x Cortex A53 cores clocked at 2.0GHz and 4 x Cortex A53 cores clocked at 1.7GHz using ARM’s big.LITTLE architecture. http://www.gizmochina.com/2016/04/28/looking-huawei-kirin-650-detail-specs/

Comment: @acejavelin Sounds like I've got the definition mixed up. Does only having different freqs make it big.LITTLE? l'm confused - if only there's a definition I can see... I'll remove the conclusion for now. Doesn't affect answering what he's asking (cores online) though.

Comment: "Homogeneous multi-core systems include only identical cores; heterogeneous multi-core systems have cores that are not identical (e.g. big.LITTLE have heterogeneous cores that shares the same instruction set)" - Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor

Comment: @acejavelin _"big.LITTLE have heterogeneous cores that shares the same instruction set"_ - that's it, thank you. Should be a good read for OP too.

Answer (score 0):

> The Huawei Kirin 650 is built on the 16nm FinFET plus process from
>   TSMC, which is much better than the 28nm process used by rivals such
>   as Helio X10 and even Snapdragon 616.
>
> As for the specs of the chip, it comes with ARM’s big.LITTLE
>   architecture with 4 x Cortex A53 cores clocked at 2.0GHz and 4 x
>   Cortex A53 cores clocked at 1.7GHz.
>   - [Source](http://www.gizmochina.com/2016/04/28/looking-huawei-kirin-650-detail-specs/)

and

> Homogeneous multi-core systems include only identical cores;
>   heterogeneous multi-core systems have cores that are not identical
>   (e.g. big.LITTLE have heterogeneous cores that shares the same
>   instruction set)
>   - [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)

Therefore the answer is the Kirin 650 processor has heterogeneous cores, and would be considered a heterogeneous processor.